# Projective varieties with an affine space as an open in them .

Tags: algebraic-geometry, birational-geometry

There is this relatively well known conjecture that any rational variety is uniformly rational. The latter means each point has a neighborhood that is isomorphic to an open in the affine space. Inspired by this I was wondering whether there are any interesting examples where a projective variety has the affine space as an open? What if we assume the complement of a hyperplane section is the affine space?